# Total reputation (sum of all reputations) of all Stack Overflow users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer, data-dump

I wanted to know if it is possible to get the total reputation of all Stack Overflow users - i.e. the sum of ALL reputation scores of ALL Stack Overflow users. I am aware that this would be a large number, since it would be simply the reputation of all users added together. I am also aware that it would be correct as of a particular time.

If it is, how is it possible? Is it from the data dump or from the data explorer?

PS. Note that I am not interested in the reputation of the entire Stack Exchange community... just Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just over one billion, according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882166/total-reputation).

```sql
SELECT SUM(CAST(Reputation AS BIGINT))
  FROM Users
```

It's not yet necessary to use a `CAST` to prevent <s>a ReputationOverflow</s> an arithmetic overflow, but it will be once the total reputation exceeds 2<sup>31</sup>, which is about 2 billion (twice the current total reputation). So this query is 'future proof'.

Comment: This is probably off by a couple million since it counts 1 rep users as having earned reputation. Also, the cast to BIGINT wasn't necessary in my testing.

Comment: @Magisch the OP wasn't asking for earned reputation, just the total.

Comment: BTW you're right about the overflow, but we're already in the same order of magnitude.

Comment: @LAD ah, crap, I'm a [long scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Long_scale) user myself but compensated in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Glorfindel I thought I was crazy for a second (deleted my comment hastily) when I didn't realize the post was edited and saw 1 billion... But, it's fixed now!

Comment: It's 1 785 937 788 =
one billion seven hundred eighty-five million nine hundred thirty-seven thousand seven hundred eighty-eight now!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, you can query this information on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882167/sum-of-all-earned-user-reputation).

I used this query to calculate all earned reputation on Stack Overflow to date.

```
SELECT 
SUM(Reputation - 1) AS [Total Reputation earned by all users]

FROM Users
WHERE Reputation > 1
```

Do note however that SEDE only updates once a week, so this is as of last sunday. Also, this excludes reputation earned by users currently suspended.

As of right now, `1.002.990.653` reputation has been earned by non suspended users on stack overflow.